# Java Casting Abstract Between Two Concrete Classes

Tags: java, casting, type-inference

I am implementing a factory pattern to create two concrete classes in an abstract which has the factory methods overloaded (see below):

```
public abstract class User {
    ...
    public static User make(int id, String name) {
        return new Admin(id, name); 
    }

    public static User make(int id, int student_id, String name) {
        return new Student(id, student_id, name); 
    }
}
```

Here is the factory calls:

```
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.asList(
        User.make(1000, "Andy"),    // makes new Admin
        User.make(1001, 101001, "Bob")    // makes new Student
    )
);
```

Here is the Admin class:

```
public class Admin extends User {
    ...
    // constructor
    protected Admin(int id, String name) {
        super(id, name);
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is the Student class:

```
public class Student extends User {
    ...
    // constructor
    protected Student(int id, int student_id, String name) {
        super(id, name);
        this.student_id = student_id;
    }
    ...
}
```

Each of these concretes are placed into a User ArrayList. I have a function (below) which loops through the list and does runtime inference to call particular methods unique to each concrete; however I am getting a ClassCastException error in my IDE stating Admin cannot be cast to Student.

Full exception message is:
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: presentation_layer.Admin cannot be cast to presentation_layer.Student**

```
public class App {
    ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(
                User.make(1000, "Andy"),        // makes new Admin
                User.make(1001, 101001, "Bob")  // makes new Student
            )
        );

        users.forEach((u) -> {
            if (u instanceof Admin)) {
                System.out.println("hello admin");
                ((Admin)u).anAdminFunc();
            } else if (u instanceof Student)) {
                System.out.println("hello student");
                ((Student)u).aStudentFunc();
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

When I comment out the concrete method calls, the respective print statements output as expected with no errors; however, when trying to use these unique method calls between each loop iteration I get the casting error. Can you please advise how this can be addressed and what I am doing wrong, with either my approach at inference or my approach at a factory pattern?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, and the complete and exact stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Can you print the result of `d.getClass().getName()` before the line that causes the class cast exception? Also, what happens when you change to `d instanceof Admin`? Could it be that either `Admin` is a class in a different package than the one imported?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I added the full exception message. I'm trying instance of now.

Comment: @Jim22150 It works for me. Could you post full example (with method `main`, initialized 'data' list and classes `User`, `Student` and `Admin`)

Comment: Please add your class declarations so that we can reproduce. There's no obvious way it could be happening like that.

Comment: I've tried your repo code and it worked **as is**. You possibly have to clean and compile again, maybe you're running a previous version that had bugs. Try to clean, rebuild, and rerun again.

Comment: The code in that link doesn't have `anAdminFunc()` and `aStudentFunc()`, so I'm guessing the code snippet here isn't *exactly* the code you're getting this error in. I totally understand wanting to simplify the code to avoid extraneous details, but I have a hunch the problem lies in one of those details you omitted.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I added more syntax which hopefully give you a better context

Comment: @ArtemPetrov I added more syntax which hopefully give you a better context

Comment: @ErnestKiwele yes I am pretty positive all of my code is correct upon further viewing.. The "aStudentFunc()" was the source of the problem during an Admin iteration; this is strange because that function should have not been called. In general, is RTI (runtime inference) bad practice, perhaps as this case illustrates ?

Comment: Your code has a method declaration inside another method declaration. It can't possibly compile. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. We must be able to copy it, paste it in our IDE, compile it and run it. You've been asked to do that several times already, but you won't. So voting to close.

Comment: @Jim22150 dynamic binding is a standard feature of Java and it's 100% okay to design and create polymorphic objects. The only thing I would change is the need to check class names at runtime. If you design by contract, then methods on `User` should be intended for both concrete types and overridden where needed. So it's more sensible to call User methods on elements of a User list, even if each element's concrete type can override or implement those methods.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say RTI is "bad practice." It might be a *code smell* that you'd notice and use as an opportunity to reevaluate whether your model design really makes sense. But I wouldn't use "this case" as an illustration of *anything* because you haven't posted code that actually reproduces the issue you're describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use instanceof instead. 
also, you might want to rethink your use of inheritance if you find yourself doing lots of casting

Comment: I tried that as well, looks like I'm getting the same exception error

Comment: instanceof can't fail. something else is happening. what do your classes look like (in terms of inheritance)?

Comment: I added some extra code that will hopefully give more context

Comment: instanceof helped me simplify my code and the inclusion of it seemed to fix my original problem upon further refactoring. Thanks @pecks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static User make(int id, String name) {
      User user = new Admin(id,name);
      return user; 
}

public static User make(int id, int student_id, String name) {
     User user = new Student(id, student_id, name);
     return user; 
}
```

reference: [parent-child type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193029/typecasting-an-object-from-parent-class-to-child)

Comment: that's effectively no different from what he has at the moment!

Comment: apparently this is the comment from another topic: `Once you create an object, you can't change its type`.

Comment: check the link in the answer @pecks

Comment: @Arun I am using Java 9 .. I see no effects from the extra syntax. Thanks but it must be something else.. I'm working on extending my question to add more code soon.